# Vertical text with CSS3 and HTML5?

Tags: html, css, svg

Using a static web-page, is there a way to rotate text 90 degrees? If so, are there any possible pit-falls with this method?

I was also considering using SVG.

Comment: http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/css-text-rotation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
p{
    transform:rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(90deg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

what he said put also include :

-webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
-moz-transform-origin:  0 0;
-ms-transform-origin:  0 0;
-o-transform-origin: 0 0;

kinda like a reset default. 
i have a live link i can send you to if needed. 
make sure you do multiple tests, if i remember correctly it didnt work in IE8.